# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the problem in the following code that causes the error?
Should I write let or function keyword before writing function?

```js
module.exports = {
    postLogin=(req, res, next) => {
        const { mobile, password } = req.body;
        User.findByCredentials(mobile, password).then((user) => {
            return user.generateAuthToken().then((token) => {
                res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
            });
        }).catch((e) => {
            res.status(400).send();
        });
    }
    getMe=(req, res, next) => {
        res.send(req.user);
    }
    getLogout=(req, res, next) => {
        req.user.removeToken(req.token).then(() => {
            res.status(200).send();
        }, () => {
            res.status(400).send();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're defining an object as the export here. So youhave to use `:` instead of `=` to define the properties like `postLogin: (req, res, next) => {`

Answer (score 0):

The right one will be:

```
module.exports = {
postLogin: (req, res, next) => {
    const { mobile, password } = req.body;
    User.findByCredentials(mobile, password).then((user) => {
        return user.generateAuthToken().then((token) => {
            res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
        });
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send();
    });
},
getMe: (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(req.user);
},
getLogout: (req, res, next) => {
    req.user.removeToken(req.token).then(() => {
        res.status(200).send();
    }, () => {
        res.status(400).send();
    });
} }
```